# How to correctly load data to Javascript's Array from external file (like .txt)

Tags: javascript, arrays, load, external

I want to load some data to the page using Javascript.

The easiest way for me is to use js Array, like below:

```
phones = ["14 211 122", "11 212 131", "666 132 123"];
```

But I feel that I shouldn't keep this kind of data in .js file. I think it should be in a separate, easier to access and edit file like .txt.

On the other hand, I'm not sure if loading data from .txt will be secure?

What should I use? Some kind of jQuery .load()? What do you suggest?

Thanks for help!

Comment: that depend on who will maintain this file, is it a developer, layman who then...security is another step, which shouldn't be consider here as it should be globally available to any action (data dependent). what you should make sure of is speed and reliability.

Comment: Adding to gwillie's point above, expanding on the speed, if it suits you more to host it in a text file or equivalent and you only have a few files, then don't worry too much. On the other hand, if you accessing many of these files then you should start thinking about performance overhead with all these requests (which would only be made worse on a mobile connection), and just embed it into the javascript (or combine it all into one text file).

Comment: So keeping this kind of data inside javascript isn't such a bad idea? 
It is better then keeping it in a separate (even combined in one) .txt file? 
Is it correct considering purposes of files (html for structure and data; css for look and simple animations; js for action etc.)?

If so, I guess it should be defined at the begining of .js in order to find and change it easily later on, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like :

```
var data;
$.ajax({url: 'values.txt'}).done(function(d) { 
    //assuming values.txt is formatted like : 1,2,3,4,5,6;
    data = JSON.parse('[' + d + ']');
});
```

However I'd recommend just storing the javascript directly instead of having to reparse it like that.

Comment: Won't work. You are assigning to the argument `data`, not the variable you declared outside the handler ;)

Comment: My bad, was half asleep.